Get rx/tx bytes per IP address
I defined one vlan which has 3 ip addresses. Now I want to get RX/TX bytes per each ip at any given time. Is it possible to use iptables, ip , netstat commands to get this? I prefer using one of pre-installed tools.
Thank you in advance.

Sure.
Let's assume your three ip addresses are:

192.168.1.10
192.168.1.20
192.168.1.30

We can create iptables rules that match inbound and outbound traffic for each address:
for addr in 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.20 192.168.1.30; do
  iptables -A INPUT -d $addr -m comment \
    --comment "account $addr in"
  iptables -A OUTPUT -s $addr -m comment \
    --comment "account $addr out"
done

The comments allow us to conveniently filter these rules using grep:
[root@node0 ~]# iptables -S |grep account
-A INPUT -d 192.168.1.10/32 -m comment --comment "account 192.168.1.10 in"
-A INPUT -d 192.168.1.20/32 -m comment --comment "account 192.168.1.20 in"
-A INPUT -d 192.168.1.30/32 -m comment --comment "account 192.168.1.30 in"
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.10/32 -m comment --comment "account 192.168.1.10 out"
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.20/32 -m comment --comment "account 192.168.1.20 out"
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.30/32 -m comment --comment "account 192.168.1.30 out"

We can see the counters using iptables -xvnL:
[root@node0 ~]# iptables -xvnL | grep account
     274    17184            0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.10         /* account 192.168.1.10 in */
     296    18552            0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.20         /* account 192.168.1.20 in */
     330    20664            0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.30         /* account 192.168.1.30 in */
     212   260913            0    --  *      *       192.168.1.10         0.0.0.0/0            /* account 192.168.1.10 out */
     230   277919            0    --  *      *       192.168.1.20         0.0.0.0/0            /* account 192.168.1.20 out */
     258   303468            0    --  *      *       192.168.1.30         0.0.0.0/0            /* account 192.168.1.30 out */

The first column in the above output is a packet counter; the second column is a byte counter. It would be easy to extract those values with your favorite text processing tools.
